# How to solve "Couldnt import module 'feast.infra.materialization.local_engine'" error

Tags: python, feast

When i try to sync features i get this error
**Could not import module 'feast.infra.materialization.local_engine' while attempting to load class 'LocalMaterializationEngine'**.
Class exist in my venv folder
[image]
Install feast this way [image]

```
try:
    repo_config = load_repo_config(repo_path, utils.get_default_yaml_file_path(repo_path))
    repo_config.registry.registry_store_type = 'core.feature_store.s3_with_aws_config_registry_store.S3WithAWSConfigRegistryStore'
    credentials_file_path = os.path.join(repo_path, "credentials.yaml")
    with open(credentials_file_path, "w") as yaml_file:
        yaml_file.write(aws_credentials_content)
    apply_total(repo_config, repo_path, False) //error raise right here
    sys.path.remove(str(repo_path))
except Exception as ex:
    sys.path.remove(str(repo_path))
    raise ex
```